# How to build a neural network that can learn to predict output images?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am working with a dataset where each input sample is a matrix, and the output corresponding to each input is also a matrix (of shape `(400, 10)`). The **input samples do not have translation invariance**. Each output image has shape `(16, 16)` . The output matrices have translation invariance.

**I want to build a neural network which can learn how to predict the output images** from the aforementioned data. It seems to me that one needs to think of a **neural network here which does regression on the output images** to learn. Presently, I am using **1000 data samples for learning in the neural network** (input samples and corresponding output images). **What is the best way to build a neural network for this task?**

Presently, I am using multi-layer perceptron (MLP) with mean square error (MSE) loss for this task. I flatten the input matrices before I feed them into the MLP, and use a standard MLP with multiple hidden layers (4-5) with many hidden units for this task.

While a visual inspection shows that the true and predicted output images are in relatively good agreement for training data, I find a **mismatch between true and predicted (reconstructed) output images for validation data**. The bottom plot shows pictures of true and predicted (reconstructed) output images for training and validation data for chosen samples.

[image]

Presently, I am using training and validation loss curves (with respect to iteration) to measure performance. I want to have a robust metric for comparison which can tell me whether the prediction is a random image or not.

**How can I get the model to generalize to the validation set better?**

The Python code that I am using for this MLP and the required data can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_Ls2Q6m-Df96JjhumHchy25kpddfCZSt/view?usp=sharing) and [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YaHmP-amz14Ev4nh5rsPi4l7XDDGq3RL/view?usp=sharing) respectively.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to AI.SE. Your post is more likely to get responded to if it consists of a single question. Also, implementation questions are off-topic here. This post has the best chance of not being closed as off-topic if you focus on conceptual questions. For more information, [see these](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) [help pages](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hi Philip, thanks for your suggestion. I have edited the question after your suggestions. I hope it is fine now :)

Comment: By saying that the input samples do not have translation invariance, do you mean that they are not images? You also say "the output corresponding to each input is also a matrix (of shape `(400, 10)`)", but then you say "Each output image has shape `(16, 16)`", so what is the difference between the output corresponding to each input sample and the output image (given that they have different dimensions)? I think you should edit your question to clarify this point (at least it is not clear to me).